# Grails VM exited with error

Tags: grails, groovy

I am facing problem in executing a the test cases for grails application. I'm using grails 2.3.7 and jdk1.7.0_25. when I am trying to perform the test-app command to test my grails application, I am getting the bellow error.

|Loading Grails 2.3.7 |Configuring classpath . |Environment set to test ...................................... |Running without daemon... Error | Error running forked test-app: org/codehaus/gant/GantBinding (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace) Error | Forked Grails VM exited with error

any guess, why this type of error comes? Please check in this regard and suggest any help.

Comment: decrease your log level

Comment: try running `grails test-app --stacktrace` (as your error message suggests) to get a bit more information. The output of that command is necessary to provide help on this! It would also be helpful if you could provide some information on what you were trying to achieve, what you've added which you think made the code fail (snippets), etc.

Comment: Also, try a more up to date version of Java 7

Comment: I have excactly the same error message using `java 1.7.0_51`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this may be an issue with a missing `tools.jar` file, according to this [bug](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9856).  Seems like it may have been [fixed](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/34e05e7a085e5a6f6f12cf3d56a8d99d8a29a1c4) in a later version of Grails, so if you can't add the jar, perhaps upgrading may help.